# Can you stop a prior page from reloading when "back" button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, reload

Doing some Intranet development.  The design approach uses a basic HTML framework populated with an ajax call (via jQuery) to populate the page.  We've standardized on Chrome for Intranet access.  The intranet allows the user to open PDF documents linked from the page in the same window, and then use the back button to return.  Our old "static" page approach retained the prior page contents - the new dynamic approach reloads the page.  How can we retain prior page content?

Research has found similar problems, but not a clear answer.  We've tried checking for an existing element in the onload() event; doesn't work because the page load is already triggered before that code gets evaluated.

The code is working correctly - our desire is to return to the already rendered page.

No errors. Getting page reload with the back button when we want to return to the already rendered prior page.

Comment: You need to track which page was last open and use that to populate the view. Implementation is up to you. Since your content comes from the AJAX call, the page will always load it's initial view unless you tell it to do something else.

Comment: URL routing is the canonical way to fix this. Sidenote: my intranet users greatly prefer having the PDF's open in a different window, so they can have multiple files open at the same time without having to navigate to the page containing the PDF links every time.

Comment: Thanks daddygames, my intention here is to not have the page reload; it does that already with the back button, but it's data intensive. We want the cached copy.  Shilly - I'll look into URL routing.  It looks like the history file and somehow forcing the cached version of the page to be used is the answer; just not sure how yet.  We may do a hybrid of what you are doing with your intranet users - when using window.open() and naming the tab, it recycles the tab over and over again. This may be a better environment than the forward/back approach.  Querying my users now on that front.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the url via the history api when you are changing the page content. This should be enough as history gets modified so the back function would work properly. However if this doesn't work you can use the url to determine what to show up on the page.

Here's an example: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/#pushState-example